# update json file dynamically whenever mysql is updated

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

i am going to create a live score board using php and mysql. But i want to create a json file which update automatically whenever i update my table on database. i mean new scores added in tables should be added in my json file. Really confused. sorry for not having any program. hope for some solutions. Thank you. i have some code which i have used to insert in database.

```
 $data = array(
'name' => $name,
'score' => $score,
'comment' => $comment
);

$result=$this->db->insert('score', $data);
```

Comment: Well then create the new JSON file after you inserted the values …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not quite understand what you want, I developed this code, see if it is what you need.

https://gist.github.com/juniorb2ss/7431040

Example:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->helper('json');
}
public function index()
{
    $data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'score' => $score,
    'comment' => $comment
    );

    save($data);

    $result = $this->db->insert('score', $data); 
}
```

File is created in folder application/cache/score.cache. Content is all scores the application.

You can enter a new score or update, the file will be updated.

Example cache content:

```
{"teste":{"name":"teste","score":"32","comment":"score comment"}}
```

Comment: But this code is not complete, it is only one version so you have an idea of how to save cache

Comment: glad to have all that query. but 'm again having problem in reinserting same data with same name. it is not replacing the data. but further adding only.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution would be to dump the whole of your score table as a JSON object on each insert. The problem with this approach is that if you have a large amount of data, on each insert you'll be selecting a lot of data.

```
function SelectScores()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM score');
    return $query->result();
}
```

You can then `json_encode` this result and save as file.